# Any tips on playing 5 and 6 note tuplets? (sheet music in desc)

Tags: piano, practice, performance-practice

http://www.gangqinpu.com/pu/2015/7/2/104346_155341.pdf
bar 66 - 73 the notes are easy but just timing the triplets with the dotted notes in the left hand (whats it called? syncopation?)

here is the reference midi

as you can see, that some of the arpeggio is played quicker.

but I have a feeling that the rhythm for both left hand and right hand is more free. I dunno maybe for consistency sake I should practice with the left hand and right hand dead on.

here is the original performance

now that I've listen to this, he accented some notes making them anchors. so maybe I should just learn the notes and later just practice anchoring the notes that he is anchoring

Answer (score 1):

It's not a 5 or 6 note "triplet" they are a 5-let and a 6-let, or 5-tuple, and 6-tuple.  You simply fit 5 (or 6) notes evenly into one beat.  So these would be played faster than a triplet.

Answer (score 1):

A sextuplet is pretty straightforward: it's a triplet on each half of the beat.  You can count it off as "one-trip-let-and-trip-let", or you can set a metronome to twice the beats per minute and play triplets against the click.

Quintuplets are a little harder.  You can syllabify them by using any five-syllable word like 'university', but methods like that get a little dicey - they're actually easier to feel than to count.

To develop a feel for them, count "1-2-3-4-5" over and over, clapping on the one count.  Then speed it up; if you reach a point where you can't enunciate fast enough, just use "dit-dit-dit-dit-dit" or any other sounds you can handle.

Once you get the right hand part down, the second half of measures 66, 68, 70, and 72 should come together fairly easily - you can think about the 12 tuplet parts as being set against 4 eighths, so you'll have one triplet against each eighth note count.  The first half of those measures and all of measures 67, 69, 71 and 73 are the real crux of the problem, because they're all five tuplet parts against four sixteenths, and the left hand is a syncopated dotted eighth-dotted eighth-eighth.

Comment: Five-syllable words starting with a plosive, e.g. paracetamol, may work better for you than five-syllable words that don't, e.g. university. But as you say, the key to mastery is repetition and internalization. I'd also suggest keeping the same metronome tick and move between various tuplet patterns - fives to sixes to fours, and so on.